# Copy selection to clipboard automatically

Tags: clipboard

I am looking for a program that can copy any selected text to the clipboard automatically. E.g. if I select some text in Microsoft Word, it should automatically copy it to the clipboard. The Google Chrome extension [Auto Copy 3.0.3](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg) can do it in Google Chrome.

Ideally, it should support as many programs as possible. I'm interested for both Windows (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate) and Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 with KDE). Free is better but not compulsory.

Comment: It is already the case with Linux, you can paste selected text with a mousewheel click.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that the same program would exist on both OSes to do this single task which is highly system-dependent. You should ask two separate questions. On Linux, what exactly are you after — selected text is automatically available as selection pasting (middle mouse wheel, keyboard shortcut in some programs), do you want it to be automatically copied to the clipboard (Ctrl+V in many programs)?

Comment: I'm not a Linux user, but [this](http://www.linuxclues.com/articles/13.htm) (untrustable) website says Linux has this feature built in. Can you check if this is correct? All you need to do is select the text... is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) which is free, but unfortunately only for Windows :(:

The script (some clever guy from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/5139-auto-copy-selected-text-to-clipboard/) has made it):

```
;Auto copy clipboard
~Lshift::
TimeButtonDown = %A_TickCount%
; Wait for it to be released
Loop
{
   Sleep 10
   GetKeyState, LshiftState, Lshift, P
   if LshiftState = U  ; Button has been released.
      break
   elapsed = %A_TickCount%
   elapsed -= %TimeButtonDown%
   if elapsed > 200  ; Button was held down long enough
   {
      x0 = A_CaretX
      y0 = A_CaretY
      Loop
   {
     Sleep 20                    ; yield time to others
     GetKeyState keystate, Lshift
     IfEqual keystate, U, {
       x = A_CaretX
       y = A_CaretY
       break
     }
   }
   if (x-x0 > 5 or x-x0 < -5 or y-y0 > 5 or y-y0 < -5)
   {                             ; Caret has moved
      clip0 := ClipBoardAll      ; save old clipboard
      ;ClipBoard =
      Send ^c                    ; selection -> clipboard
      ClipWait 1, 1              ; restore clipboard if no data
      IfEqual ClipBoard,, SetEnv ClipBoard, %clip0%
   }
      return
   }
}

~LButton::
MouseGetPos, xx
TimeButtonDown = %A_TickCount%
; Wait for it to be released
Loop
{
   Sleep 10
   GetKeyState, LButtonState, LButton, P
   if LButtonState = U  ; Button has been released.
   {
      If WinActive("Crimson Editor") and (xx < 25) ; Single Click in the Selection Area of CE
      {
         Send, ^c
         return
      }
      break
   }
   elapsed = %A_TickCount%
   elapsed -= %TimeButtonDown%
   if elapsed > 200  ; Button was held down too long, so assume it's not a double-click.
   {
      MouseGetPos x0, y0            ; save start mouse position
      Loop
   {
     Sleep 20                    ; yield time to others
     GetKeyState keystate, LButton
     IfEqual keystate, U, {
       MouseGetPos x, y          ; position when button released
       break
     }
   }
   if (x-x0 > 5 or x-x0 < -5 or y-y0 > 5 or y-y0 < -5)
   {                             ; mouse has moved
      clip0 := ClipBoardAll      ; save old clipboard
      ;ClipBoard =
      Send ^c                    ; selection -> clipboard
      ClipWait 1, 1              ; restore clipboard if no data
      IfEqual ClipBoard,, SetEnv ClipBoard, %clip0%
   }
      return
   }
}
; Otherwise, button was released quickly enough.  Wait to see if it's a double-click:
TimeButtonUp = %A_TickCount%
Loop
{
   Sleep 10
   GetKeyState, LButtonState, LButton, P
   if LButtonState = D  ; Button has been pressed down again.
      break
   elapsed = %A_TickCount%
   elapsed -= %TimeButtonUp%
   if elapsed > 350  ; No click has occurred within the allowed time, so assume it's not a double-click.
      return
}

;Button pressed down again, it's at least a double-click
TimeButtonUp2 = %A_TickCount%
Loop
{
   Sleep 10
   GetKeyState, LButtonState2, LButton, P
   if LButtonState2 = U  ; Button has been released a 2nd time, let's see if it's a tripple-click.
      break
}
;Button released a 2nd time
TimeButtonUp3 = %A_TickCount%
Loop
{
   Sleep 10
   GetKeyState, LButtonState3, LButton, P
   if LButtonState3 = D  ; Button has been pressed down a 3rd time.
      break
   elapsed = %A_TickCount%
   elapsed -= %TimeButtonUp%
   if elapsed > 350  ; No click has occurred within the allowed time, so assume it's not a tripple-click.
   {  ;Double-click
      Send, ^c
      return
   }
}
;Tripple-click:
   Sleep, 100
   Send, ^c
return

~^a::Send, ^c ;Ctl+A = Select All, then Copy
```

For it to work, the text must be selected by:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys,
- Left mouse button, or
- Double click, or
- Triple click, or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

It works great! All you need to do is select the text, and it is already there in your clipboard! AutoHotKey works throughout the OS afaik.

Comment: Can you modify it so that we can paste with a mouse middle button click ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Diodon](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Diodon) on Ubuntu. Type these commands one by one in the Terminal. Enter your password when prompted:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install diodon
```

Comment: What does diodon do?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/) for Linux. It should be already in Ubuntu repos.