# Automatically copy after a double-click sent programmatically on Windows

Tags: windows, clipboard, mouse

I am looking for a program for Windows that can modify the behavior of a double-click so that each double-click is followed by a  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>.

[This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9930/903) provides a great AHK script, but it doesn't work for me for double-clicks, because apparently AHK doesn't recognize double-clicks sent programmatically, i.e. not for the mouse but through some other software emulating mouse clicks (in my case  [SmartNAV](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html) +  [Point-N-Click Virtual Mouse](http://www.polital.com/pnc/)).

Comment: Doesn't [the AHK script in this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9930/6834) also work for double clicks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy selection to clipboard automatically](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/copy-selection-to-clipboard-automatically)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  That question asks to copy all selected text to the clipboard automatically.  This question asks for it to be copied to the clipboard with a double-click.  The AutoHotKey script in the other answer, assuming it works as described, will copy text to the clipboard even without a double-click.  The questions look similar, but do not look like duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, good point, I had forgotten about it.  I am actually using this script for automatically putting in clipboard after a Ctrl+A. But it doesn't work for me for double-clicks, because apparently AHK doesn't recognize double-clicks send programmatically, i.e. not for the mouse but through some other software emulating mouse clicks (in my case  [SmartNAV](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html) +  [Point-N-Click Virtual Mouse](http://www.polital.com/pnc/)). I think having a dedicated question for it would help focusing on this specific feature for a specific OS.